# Which versions of firefox does angularjs support?

Tags: angularjs, firefox, browser

In the [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq), they say Angular supports Webkit, Firefox, IE>8. 
But which versions of Firefox exactly?

I need to create an app with Firefox 25 support. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJs is a Javascript framework and (except for weird cases like IE8 which they're [dropping support](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) in the 1.3 release) should work for such a high rev of Firefox.

Since they're say which IE version they support and not Chrome or Firefox, we can assume all the versions are working.

See the [FAQs](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old thread, but for anyone else who stumbles upon this (like I did), I can get Angular 1.3beta to work (routing, view rendering, dependency injection) on Firefox 4.

**However**, you can go even further back (I've gotten it to run on 3.6.3, which was the lowest practical limit for my user base) if you use the shim [provided by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (Angular 1.3beta uses Object.keys; support for this was added in Firefox 4 according the preceding MDN article).