# What browsers does AngularJS work with?

Tags: html, angularjs, browser, cross-browser

This can be a most common question. But no any clue about browser versions. More over, [Angular site](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#what-browsers-does-angularjs-work-with-) itself says as following.

> > What browsers does Angular work with?
>
> We run our extensive test suite against the following browsers: the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Safari for iOS, as well as Internet Explorer versions 9-11. See Internet Explorer Compatibility for more details on supporting legacy IE browsers.
>
> If a browser is untested, it doesn't mean it won't work. You can also expect browsers to work that share a large part of their codebase with a browser we test, such as Opera 15 or newer (uses the Blink engine), or the various Firefox derivatives.
>
> [— AngularJS FAQ - What browsers does AngularJS work with?](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#what-browsers-does-angularjs-work-with-)

However, there is no any note which versions are supported. I googled, but couldn't find. Any one let me know what browsers and their versions do support which version of angular ?

Comment: They don't specify versions for Chrome, Safari, and FF because it's irrelevant. Nobody uses versions of those browsers that angular wouldn't work on.

Comment: other than Internet Explorer or Opera, (IE9+, Opera 15+ both mentioned in the quoted documentation), the version doesn't matter.

Comment: See also [AngularJS FAQ - Version Support Status](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Browser support of `AngularJS`:

*Internet Explorer*: 9+

**Versions 1.2** and later of `AngularJS` do not support Internet Explorer versions 6 or 7.
**Versions 1.3** and later of `AngularJS` dropped support for Internet Explorer 8.

*Opera 15+*

*Firefox, Safari, and Google Chrome*

As mentioned in a **StackOverflow** Question here: [Which versions of firefox does angularjs support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873053/which-versions-of-firefox-support-angularjs), since they say which IE version they support and not Chrome, Safari, or Firefox, it's safe to assume all the versions are working.

Answer (score 1):

> ### Version Support Status
>
> Any version branch not shown in the following table (e.g. 1.6.x) is no longer being developed.
>
> ```
> Version   Status              Comments
> 1.2.x     Long Term Support   Last version to provide IE 8 support
> 1.7.x     Long Term Support   See Long Term Support section below.
> ```
>
> ## Long Term Support
>
> At this time we will focus exclusively on providing fixes to bugs that satisfy at least one of the following criteria:
>
> - A security flaw is detected in the 1.7.x branch of the framework
> - One of the major browsers releases a version that will cause current production applications using AngularJS 1.7.x to stop working
> - The jQuery library releases a version that will cause current production applications using AngularJS 1.7.x to stop working.
>
> [— AngularJS Documentation - Version Support Status](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status)

Answer (score 0):

According to AngularJS document：[Internet Explorer Compatibility](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie), the answer should be IE 9。

> AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. Read more about it on our blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier.
>
> The project currently supports and will attempt to fix bugs for IE9 and above. The continuous integration server runs all the tests against IE9, IE10, and IE11.