# angularjs is not working in old versions of browsers

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i created a website in angularjs  which is working fine in new broswer but it is not working fine in old versions of broswers in old browsers it is showing some content and other content is not showing. Can any one help me to sort out it..

Comment: Which browsers are you trying to use it in? Which work / don't work?

Comment: chrome and mozilla and safari

Comment: in new versions of chrome and safari is working fine

Comment: usually there would be an error in the console, try reading it (F12 accesses it I believe). Some features, like arrow notation are not supported on older browsers, so you might want to compile JS with Babel.js

Comment: @AlekseySolovey there is a known bug in AngularJS 1.14 and before (possibly after too) with arrow notations. At the time of making AngularJS was not supposed to support ES6 in global. Later, Angular switched to Typescript.

Comment: Angular 1.2.x is the last version to support IE8. See [AngularJS MISC Documentation - Support Status](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What browsers does AngularJS work with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017816/what-browsers-does-angularjs-work-with)