# Did Angularjs Supports Mozilla Firefox browser 3.0.11 version

Tags: angularjs

Do you know whether the AngularJS Supports Mozilla Firefox browser 3.0.11 version? I have developed the app using AngularJS, but it doesn't work in the browser version. Please tell me what is the least Mozilla Firefox version which supports AngularJS.

Edit:

Spec : Browser - Firefox 3.0.11, AngularJS v1.3.1

Code:

```
<body data-ng-controller="samplesController">   
    <script type="text/javascript">
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = (function() {
    'use strict';
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({ toString: null }).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
        dontEnums = [
          'toString',
          'toLocaleString',
          'valueOf',
          'hasOwnProperty',
          'isPrototypeOf',
          'propertyIsEnumerable',
          'constructor'
        ],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

    return function(obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object' && (typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null)) {
        throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
      }

      var result = [], prop, i;

      for (prop in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
          result.push(prop);
        }
      }

      if (hasDontEnumBug) {
        for (i = 0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) {
            result.push(dontEnums[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
  }());
}
    </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Error Screenshot:

[image]

Edit1:

FireBug's Stack trace

[image]

Edit2:

I have added the below two lines above angularjs

```
<script src="js/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="js/es5-sham.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
```

But still i receive two errors

[image]

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/25204540/1839655, someone got Angular 1.3 to work in Firefox 3.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `id="ng-app"` near your `ng-app="app"` declaration.

```
<html ng-app="app" id="ng-app">
```

It will work with IE 8 and sometimes firefox too, and try lowering the version of angularjs with 1.2.x

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS only provides compatibility information for Internet Explorer.

However, AngularJS 1.3.x is known not to be compatible with Firefox 3 because of usage of `Object.keys`.

See this answer to make AngularJS compatible with Firefox 3 (using an Object.keys shim): https://stackoverflow.com/a/25204540/451480

Comment: Where we need to add this Object.keys shim in the code. because i have included the code in my app, but the results remain the same, not working in the mentioned browser.

Comment: include it before including AngularJS. Can you post the error that you're seeing?

Comment: Error: H is not a function
Source File: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js
Line: 7

Error: angular.module is not a function
Source File: http://127.0.0.1:52460/index.html
Line: 82

Error: Object.keys is not a function
Source File: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967308/did-angularjs-supports-mozilla-firefox-browser-3-0-11-version?answertab=oldest#tab-top
Line: 846\

Error: no element found
Source File: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29967308/ivc/d6c8?_=1430401671659
Line: 1

Comment: We have provided the code we are trying in the edit. Kindly check it

Comment: Can you use the non-minified version of AngularJS and include a stack trace? (using Firebug 1.7.3)

Comment: Here's the firebug's stack trace

Comment: isArray is not a function
forEach()angular.js (line 335)
anonymous(Window index.html, Document index.html, Object name=undefined)angular.js (line 2745)
angular.js()angular.js (line 25623)
[Break on this error] } else if (isArray(obj) || isArrayLike(obj)) {\nangular.js (line 335)
angular.module is not a function
index.html()index.html (line 82)
[Break on this error] <script data-brackets-id='524'>\nindex.html (line 82)

Comment: @Blaise for clear understanding i have included a screenshot above

Comment: Thanks. You also need an `Array.isArray` shim. To prevent any usage of ES5 creating an error, you could include https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim and see if it works at all with all ES5 shims.

Comment: I have added the below two lines above angularjs 

<script src="js/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="js/es5-sham.js"></script>

But still i receive two errors

Comment: document.querySelector is not a function
anonymous()angular.js (line 953)
angular.js()angular.js (line 25625)
[Break on this error] var active = !!(document.querySelector('[ng-csp]') ||\nangular.js (line 953)
element.querySelector is not a function
anonymous()angular.js (line 1359)
forEach()angular.js (line 339)
angularInit()angular.js (line 1355)
anonymous()angular.js (line 25620)
trigger()angular.js (line 2709)
anonymous()angular.js (line 2979)
[Break on this error] if (!appElement && (candidate = elem...' + name.replace(':', '\\:') + ']'))) {\nangular.js (line 1359)

Comment: You could try including jQuery (before your include Angular) to fix that, if that doesn't work, I think our adventure ends here. querySelector was introduced in Firefox 3.5 and I don't know of any shim for non-IE browsers.

Comment: @Blaise I tried still now working, anyway thanks for your help.